# c# xml serialization custom elementName

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I am trying to serialize an class object into xml that looks like this:

```
<Colors>
<Blue>
  <R>0,000</R>
  <G>0,000</G>
  <B>1,000</B>
  <A>1,000</A>
</Blue>
<Red>
  <R>1,000</R>
  <G>0,000</G>
  <B>0,000</B>
  <A>1,000</A>
</Red></Colors>
```

The important part is that the colors blue and red are not specified directly. I have a class like this:

```
public class Color
{
    [XmlElement("R")]
    public string red;

    [XmlElement("G")]
    public string green;

    [XmlElement("B")]
    public string blue;

    [XmlElement("A")]
    public string alpha;
}
```

What I need is a way to create instances of the `Color` class object and serialize them with different names like `blue, red, green, anothercolor1, anothercolor2, ...`
also it must be posible to add new colors dynamicly while the programm runs.

I know I could add attributes to the Color class but I cant change the layout of the xml, so I have to find another way.

Any ideas?

Comment: And how/where do you store the name?  Does it have to use a specific serializer?

Comment: The XML provided does not make sense, it should be `<Colors><Color Name="Red">..</Color></Colors>`

Comment: @HenkHolterman: for the moment i did not store the names, i would do it in the color class if needed. i also thought about using a second class and make a sortedlist<string name, Color color> with the color class objects and the names in it, but i cant serialize a sortedlist or did i miss something?

Comment: @BasB: i know that this xml doesnt make sense. i would do it the way you describ, but i cant change the layout of the xml.

Comment: Dear Benedikt H., Do you want to change xml text more readable. If yes, you can try to use xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented; xmlTextWriter.Indentation = 3; before write string into text.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use reflection to [get all the properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx) of the Color class and iterate through them:

```
public void SerializeAllColors()
{
    Type colorType = typeof(System.Drawing.Color);
    PropertyInfo[] properties = colorType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
    {
        string name = p.Name;
        Color c = p.GetGetMethod().Invoke(null, null);

        //do your serialization with name and color here
    }
}
```

Edit: If you aren't in control to change the XML format and you know the format won't change, you could additionally just hardcode the serialization yourself:

Outside the foreach loop:

```
string file = "<Colors>\n";
```

Within the loop:

```
file += "\t<" + name + ">\n";
file += "\t\t<R>" + color.R.ToString() + "</R>\n";
file += "\t\t<G>" + color.G.ToString() + "</G>\n";
file += "\t\t<B>" + color.B.ToString() + "</B>\n";
file += "\t\t<A>" + color.A.ToString() + "</A>\n";
file += "\t</" + name + ">\n";
```

And at the very end:

```
file += "</Colors>"
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"colors.xml"))
{
    writer.Write(file);
}
```

Replace `\n` with `\r\n` or with `Environment.NewLine` as you please